# How do I prevent daydream mode in an Amazon FireTV HTML5 web app?

Tags: android, html, amazon-fire-tv

I'm building a FireTV HTML5 web app and my FireTV Stick keeps going into Daydream/Screensaver mode.  I see from the FAQs (https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/amazon-fire-tv-sdk-frequently-asked-questions) that I can disable this using the KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag, but since I'm building an HTML5 app, not an Android app, I don't know how to set this flag.

Is there a way to disable Daydream mode from a FireTV web app?

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the app to the developer portal there is a checkbox that allows you to disable that. 
Provided that you created a new "Mobile Web" app in your console you will see "Prevent Sleep for Video Playback" in the "App file(s)" tab.

More info [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/webapps/faq#Fire%20TV%20Web%20Apps)

In alternative, you can create a wrapper for the webview yourself and add the KEEP_SCREEN_ON in your mainActivity.

Comment: Thanks!  Does this prevent the screensaver from appearing *no matter what*? Or does it really only work during video playback?  It's now been 2 months since I was working on this, but I'm pretty sure I tried this already and found that unless I was actually playing a video, the screen saver would still pop up.

Comment: Correct. It will only prevent the screensaver only if a video is playing (ie. the <video> object is in play state. If you wish to prevent the screensaver throughout the whole app (not recommended, could lead to bad customer experience) you will have to create a wrapper yourself